# What can be used for SSO in java web application

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat9

I'm developing a Java web application using Tomcat 9.In the Login page, I want a tool that can authenticate the user's credentials and sign him in automatically. Is there any simple example that can help, as I'm kind of new to Java development. In addition, I want the User's username and password to be fetched from the Operating system.

Thank you

Comment: If you are using Spring, then Spring Security is a great framework to consider: https://spring.io/projects/spring-security

Comment: Actually no I'm using Eclipse as a framework  @NotaJD

Comment: Use Kerberos for integrated Windows authentication . [Go through link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use Kerberos via SPNEGO: http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/

works perfectly for me and my users